# Parent Directory '../' going up two directories

Tags: javascript, directory, parent

I am very confused.

I have been testing a site I am building on one server, and on that server I have a link to a javascript file.  On said server I link to the file with `'../js/javascript.js'` and the file loads properly.  On another server I just switched to, if I use the same link the file does not load.  I look at firebug and see it seems that `'../'` is going up two directories and returning a 404 error.

I have fixed the path on the new server, but I am confused about the inconsistency.

I believe it has to do with the fact that I call the javascript in my header.php file, which is in a directory called inc.  however the index.php where I include my header.php is in the root directory.  But, I don't understand why on one server it references from the root and on the other it references from inside the `inc` directory.

```
site/
    index.php
    js/
       javascript.js
    inc/
       header.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not matter where header.php exists, because it gets included in index.php before the page is delivered to the browser.  So any `<script src="...">` tags will be relative to index.php.  So, your HTML for including the js file should be:

```
<script src="js/javascript.js">
```

No `../`!  Not sure why it worked on the old server, but it definitely won't work on the new one as you've described it.

Comment: Ok, thank you.  This makes much more sense as I have been taught that, as you said, include basically just pastes everything into the file before the browser reads it.  If anyone understands a reason for the inconsistency I am very curious to know.  I still have the site up on the old server if anyone would like to take a look.  http://magusdrums.co.nf/index.php

Comment: If the old server used chroot to make site the effective root of the directory tree, then going to site’s .. brings you back to site.

Comment: Ahh I see, that makes sense.  So in this case it would not matter if I used .. or not on the old server?